# Reduce EleasticSearch Restart Delay

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, sharding

I am restarting Elasctic-Search Nodes, I am having 5 nodes with heapSize of 12 GB each , and 45000 shards. restarting each node is taking lot of time.

Is there any way I can improve restarting time without loosing data.

Comment: You have 9000 shards per node, it is too much, with 12 GB you should have something near 240 shards per node. What is your shard size? How many GB? You will need to review your sharding strategy and add more nodes. Read [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) for more tips about sharding.

Comment: @leandrojmp I have Shards with different Size, Min. is 18 MB Max is 100.

Comment: You will need to change the number and size of your shards to improve your restarting time, 100 MB is too small, one of the best practices is to keep shards size between a few GB and tens GB, something like 20 GB, 30 GB. Also, before restarting a node do a [flushed sync](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-synced-flush.html)